# Continuity of $f(x,y,z)=1/(x+y+z-\sqrt{3})$

Tags: calculus

Is the function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x+y+z-\sqrt{3}}$ continuous, if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: Let $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, then we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, but $x+y+z=\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}$. Then the denominator is 0, so the function isn't even defined at all points $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is undefined when
$$x+y+z=\sqrt{3}$$
So you need to check if this surface intersects the unit sphere.
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(x+y+z)^2=3 \le (x^2+y^2+z^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2)$$

Equality holds when $$x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$.
Hence, the points of at where the function is undefined are all outside the unit sphere except at $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$, where it intersects the sphere.

The domain of the function on the sphere can hence only be $S^2-(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$.

Inside this domain $D$, it is continuous.

Comment: Note that the point $x=y=z=1/\sqrt3$ is not a _discontinuity_. The function just isn't defined there.